# Two Functionalities for same routes at same time on Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm doing an application Web+Flask (Python). Actually, it accepts email and an image using an HTML form, and when we click on submits, it should redirect a page called "submit.html" and also doing some couple of operations that takes more time.

So, I thought when we click submit button, it should appear some text as, "We are working on it. Will sent the work to you an email" which is in "submit.html". I don't know how to do this. The image processing would take more time (hours), we shouldn't set the page on loading until the work is complete and return the rendered_template ('submit.html').

Suggest the code or any other good approach to fit this scenario.

**Python Code**

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file-ip-1']
        emailadd=request.form['email']
        print(emailadd)

        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(basepath, 'web', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)
        print(file_path)
        runn(file_path,emailadd)
    return render_template('submit.html')

def runn(file_path,emailadd):
    s=Splits()
    tokens,h,w,ext = s.get_tokens(file_path)
    print(len(tokens))
    d=ops.main()
    if d:
        i=s.get_image('inputs/',w,ext)
        print(i,emailadd)

        D=Deliver().send_email(emailadd,i)
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: you should use redis for long running task

Comment: how? will that work? Please give some reference?

Comment: check this (https://towardsdatascience.com/use-redis-queue-for-asynchronous-tasks-in-a-flask-app-d39f2a8c2667)